# Can't play on my friends world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Every time my friend and I try to play together on local wifi, his name won't show up for me to join in the world selection screen. We both have the same update (11.1) and we both use the same wifi. What's going on?

Comment: Minecraft PC or PE? You need to be clearer. There is no 11.1 for PC. So we assume you are on PC

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is the options. Does your friend have "local server multiplayer" enabled?

If that option is enabled then it must be a networking isse, your two iPads might not be able to "see" each other on the wifi connection.

Comment: What først thing?

Comment: Damned danish spellchecker :-)

Comment: Its ok. We all make mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you both are on the same wireless network and wifi is enabled on both computers. Your friend will then need to run the command /publish in single player mode after which you should be able to see "LAN Server" under multiplayer

If your friend is not using a single player world and is running a actuall server find the local ip of the computer running the server by running ipconfig in command prompt on the computer running the server and then use that ip when clicking add server or direct connect. (Use localhost if server is on same computer trying to connect)